# Sublime Text 3083 CMD.exe error

Tags: python, cmd, sublimetext3

just upgraded to 3083 from 3065, every time i run a script I get:

```
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

The script still runs but it makes me uncomfortable seeing that every time I do a build.  This was not occuring in 3065, how can I elminate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Because having a UNC directory as a default can cause programs started in the console to crash if the console is closed. In testing I have never seen a program crash. It's probably meant for very old programs.

There is a registry key to allow UNC paths.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
DisableUNCCheck = DWord (1 = true, 0 or absent = false)
```

However CMD won't let you change to one. The only way to make this happen is to start CMD from a shortcut with the default directory set to a UNC path (and probably any other command that allows default path to be set for a program being started).

So how are you starting it? Look there for the directory being specified. Is anything on a network, or specified as if on a network (ie 127.0.0.1 or localhost or *machinename*)